# invalid path argument in R

Tags: r, arguments

I had tried to  execute this function to find correlation between two elements in the  excel files of directory "specdata",by passing in the command line `corr("specdata")`. But  it shows  " Error in list.files(directory, full.names = TRUE) :  invalid 'path' argument ". I had checked the current working directory and it was correct. Any ideas for the reason of error ?

```
     corr <- function(directory , threshold=0){   
               files_all <- list.files( directory , full.names = TRUE )  
               v <- c(mode = "numeric" , length = 0 )
               for ( i in  1:length(files_all)) {
                   individual <- read.csv(files_all[i] , head = TRUE )
                   nobs <- sum(complete.cases(individual))
                   if ( nobs > threshold ) {
                      xSulfate <- individual[which(!is.na(individual$sulfate)),]
                      yPollutant <- xSulfate[which(!is.na(xSulfate$nitrate)),]
                      v <- c( v , cor(yPollutant$sulfate,yPollutant$nitrate))

                      }     
                  }              

        return v       
 }
```

Comment: use browser() method inside your function to debug and you will know the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `corr()` function in the Johns Hopkins University *R Programming* course assignment makes the assumption that the `specdata` directory is a subdirectory of the current R working directory.

One way to retrieve the list of files from this subdirectory is to retrieve the current directory with `getwd()` and use this to build the full path to use as an argument to `list.files()`.

```
 ## obtain a list of all the CSV files in directory
 theList <- list.files(paste0(getwd(),"/",directory))
```

Another approach is to combine `./` with the `directory` argument.

```
 theList <- list.files(paste0("./",directory))
```

### Did I unzip specdata correctly?

Students are given instructions to download the data file required for the assignment, `specdata.zip` and unzip it in the current R working directory. The zip file contains a directory, and the unzip process creates the directory and stores 332 pollution sensor data files in the subdirectory.

We can confirm the current R directory and whether `specdata` is a subdirectory from the working directory as follows.

```
# first, get working directory
getwd()
# second, confirm specdata is a subdirectory of this directory
dir.exists("./specdata")
```

...and the output:

```
> # first, get working directory
> getwd()
[1] "/Users/lgreski/gitrepos/datascience"
> # second, confirm specdata is a subdirectory of this directory
> dir.exists("./specdata")
[1] TRUE
>
```